# Attaching media to custom posts without editor

Tags: custom-post-types, attachments

I'm creating a custom post type, "gallery", in which the admin should be able to upload images (these images would be attached to the post).

The thing is that the "editor" meta box is disabled for this post type. And I need a way to add the image upload pop-up box to it, just like posts have. How can I do that?

or maybe it's better to create my own uploader? if so, how could I attach the uploaded images to the post (gallery) that's being created?

how do attachments work? are they custom post types too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[At the top of `wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php#L21) I see the following code that seems related to the media uploader:

```
if ( post_type_supports($post_type, 'editor') || post_type_supports($post_type, 'thumbnail') ) {
    add_thickbox();
    wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
}
```

You'll need to add these yourself. [`add_thickbox()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-includes/general-template.php#L2133) enqueues both a script and a style, so make sure you hook into `print_styles`, as `print_scripts` will be too late to also print a style.

```
add_action('admin_print_styles-post-new.php', 'wpa4016_add_media_upload_scripts');
add_action('admin_print_styles-post.php', 'wpa4016_add_media_upload_scripts');
function wpa4016_add_media_upload_scripts()
{
    if ($GLOBALS['post_type'] == 'wpa4016') {
        add_thickbox();
        wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
    }
}
```

Now we need to add the upload buttons. I see [`the_editor()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-includes/general-template.php#L1778), the function that displays the editor, has a parameter `$media_buttons`, and if we set to to `true` it basically executes `do_action('media_buttons')`. This in turn calls [`media_buttons()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-admin/includes/media.php#L353), which calls `_media_button()` for each media type (image, video, audio, ...). So we do this ourselves!

```
add_action('edit_form_advanced', 'wpa4016_edit_form_advanced');
function wpa4016_edit_form_advanced()
{
    if ($GLOBALS['post_type'] == 'wpa4016') {
        echo _media_button(__('Add an Image'), 'images/media-button-image.gif?ver=20100531', 'image');
    }
}
```

Attachments are indeed custom posts of type `attachment`, with their `post_parent` set to the post they're attached to. Images have two meta fields: `_wp_attached_file` contains the filename, `_wp_attachment_metadata` contains an array with image EXIF data and pointers to different sizes of the same image. You can create these yourself, using [`wp_insert_attachment()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment), but I believe you still have to handle the upload yourself then.

Comment: tx, i tried this and it works, kind of. the problem is that functionality is limited. "insert into post" button missing, gallery tab acting weird. So I guess it's better to make my own upload function. I assume wp_handle_upload() will take care of the uploaded files, but how can I attach these files to the current post?

Comment: @Alex: If the attached file has its `post_parent` field set to the post ID of your "gallery" post, you can get all images via a `get_children()` query. That's how "normal" attachments work.

Comment: tx, wp insert attachment() seems to do what I want. Any suggestions for a good multifile uploader?

Comment: Nice answer. I'll look into this too - seems like a lot of people have been wanting this kind of functionality...

Comment: Alex asked [a followup question about the upload handler](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4019/any-plugin-out-there-that-uses-wps-internal-image-uploader), now they are linked.

Answer (score 1):

Above answer is very helpful answer but sad thing is _media_button() function is deprecated from wp 3.5

So i have changed above code like this :

Replace this line of code `echo _media_button(__('Add an Image'), 'images/media-button-image.gif?ver=20100531', 'image');`

With these lines :

```
$img = '<span class="wp-media-buttons-icon"></span> ';
       echo '<a href="#" class="button insert-media add_media" data-editor="' . esc_attr( $editor_id ) . '" title="' . esc_attr__( 'Add Media' ) . '">' . $img . __( 'Add Media' ) . '</a>';
```

and finally I used code to add media button to my gallery post type is like this

```
add_action('admin_print_styles-post-new.php', 'gallery_add_media_upload_scripts');
add_action('admin_print_styles-post.php', 'gallery_add_media_upload_scripts');
function gallery_add_media_upload_scripts()
{
    if ($GLOBALS['post_type'] == 'gallery') {
        add_thickbox();
        wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
    }
}

add_action('edit_form_advanced', 'gallery_edit_form_advanced');
function gallery_edit_form_advanced()
{
    if ($GLOBALS['post_type'] == 'gallery') {
        $img = '<span class="wp-media-buttons-icon"></span> ';
       echo '<a href="#" class="button insert-media add_media" data-editor="' . esc_attr( $editor_id ) . '" title="' . esc_attr__( 'Add Media' ) . '">' . $img . __( 'Add Media' ) . '</a>';
    }
}
```

Comment: `add_thickbox()` will likely also get deprecated.

Comment: I dont know about `add_thickbox()` but above code worked well for theme...

Comment: This doesn't work if your custom post type doesn't use an editor.

Comment: @CamTullos You are right. I added this button because my custom post type not supported with editor

Comment: Button showing but do not working in 3.5.2

Comment: @Bohdan Hdal It should work. I have no problem at all in 3.5.2

Comment: What is `$editor_id` supposed to be? Anyway tried the code and it does not seem to work in 3.6 without an editor.