# Any plugin out there that uses WP's internal image uploader?

Tags: plugins, media, uploads

I'm trying to use the media uploader thing from WP (the form from the pop-up with crunching and all that), and can't figure out how.

Is there any plugin out there that uses it? It would be easier to understand...

Comment: Small tip: if you want to search for a plugin that uses a specific function, you can use [Google Code Search](http://www.google.com/codesearch) with `package:svn.wp-plugins.org` and the function name.

Comment: handy tip, handier than svn'n local get of all plugins...

Comment: what exactly cant you figure out?

Comment: well, I'm building a gallery using custom post types, and need to open a thickbox when a link is pressed, in which to insert wp's upload form, but only the upload part, not the entire media-uploader pop-up.

Comment: @Jan Fabry: thanks, didn't find any :( so far your answer on my other questions is the closest to what I'm looking for

Comment: If you want to use the uploader in metafields, you can try out this plugin https://github.com/jaredatch/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin [Image Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/image-widget/) uses it.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/image-widget/

Answer (score 2):

[This is](http://www.webmaster-source.com/2010/01/08/using-the-wordpress-uploader-in-your-plugin-or-theme/) the best tutorial there is on using the (old, pre-3.3, non-Plupload) media uploader.