# More Fields & Media Upload

Tags: uploads, media-library, customization

I'm using the [more types](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/more-types/), [more fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/more-fields/) and [more taxonomies](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/more-taxonomies/) plugins and they're beyond excellent. However, I've found that once I remove the main wysiwyg block I no longer have access to the media upload buttons. [image]

I've searched extensively for an option that would give me a new upload field or different buttons but have been unsuccessful. I read this brilliant answer by [MathSmath](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4307/how-can-i-add-an-image-upload-field-directly-to-a-custom-write-panel)
But I'm unsure how I would implement it with more-fields. I also found an [article](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-more-fields-feature-request-file-upload?replies=11) indicating that the developer wouldn't provide this option so I'm stuck figuring it out myself.

I've gone so deep down the rabbit hole with these plugins that there's no turning back. Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Zach, can you post a pastebin or other code to show how you edited? Post in that other forum too, maybe they can incorporate into next version....

Comment: well, since zach doesn't want to share his code, a quick solution to those who find this, add a "featured image" metabox to your custom post type (supports => thumbnail) and you can use that to upload images to gallery. inelegant, but it works.

Comment: ok so I went ahead and created a pastebin post with the code I was working with http://pastebin.com/vA4yeXxp. It absolutely shows the media upload button and field but doesn't pop the thick-box. Let me know if you have any ideas.

Comment: Here's another post related to the port I'm trying to do http://www.webmaster-source.com/2010/01/08/using-the-wordpress-uploader-in-your-plugin-or-theme/#

Comment: zach, there are a few things wrong with that script, i'm gonna try to fix it and report back. you copied and pasted but its checking certain conditionals and therefore not putting the jquery in the admin header which is likely the problem

Comment: @yonation thanks! Also found this while browsing the "related" panel to the right http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4307/how-can-i-add-an-image-upload-field-directly-to-a-custom-write-panel

Comment: Any results, Yonation?

Comment: @Zach Shallbetter Why did you mark this as solution if there's no solution so far?

Comment: Hmm unsure, I don't remember doing that.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known bug that they're not responding to, see here on their forum:

http://more-plugins.se/forum/topic/insert-image-button-not-working

Comment: Thanks James, I posted to it as well. I sincerely need this ability in some form. Even if I could just add a custom bar that allows for media upload within custom posts that would be fine.

Comment: It's not a plugin bug its cuased by the post type that dosen't support either the editor or thumbnail so the media upload scripts are not included.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Jan's answer to [Attaching media to custom posts without editor](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4016/attaching-media-to-custom-posts-without-editor)
you'll see that the post type must support either "editor" or "thumbnail"
to include it by default, but he also shows how to include it yourself.

Comment: I'm completely unsure how to do this with the more_fields plugin. I've been working with the link below a bit this morning but haven't gotten the thickbox to pop. I'll play with the one you posted to see if I can get any further with it. If you have any idea please let me know. http://www.webmaster-source.com/2010/01/08/using-the-wordpress-uploader-in-your-plugin-or-theme

Comment: You wont be able to do it using more fields unless you edit so of the plugin files.  The plugin creates the metabox using its own code and you won't be able to add the code you need to display the media upload thickbox. Your best chance is to create your own metabox.

Comment: I was able to add the upload field from the tutorial within more-fields-field-types.php. the only thing I couldn't pull off was getting the tickbox to launch.

Comment: Ok so you are editing the plugins file, nice create a pastebin of your code and i'll take a look